# Как создать игру в telegram?

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, telegram-bot

[Создал бота.](https://core.telegram.org/bots/games#creating-a-game) Включил `inline` режим. Зарегистрировал игру `(/newgame)`. Привязал её к боту... Даже инлайн сообщения с игрой могу кидать.
Не могу понять куда запихнуть `url`? Нужно ли создавать объект типа `Game` и как его передавать в `inlinequery`.
Ни на ютубе, ни в гугле - нигде нет даже простого гайда по созданию игры, привязке к боту и расшариванию её.

Answer (score 3):

**Телеграму** не нужно знать ни `HTML`, ни `CSS`, ни `JS` коды вашей игры.
Нужно только 3 основные составляющие.

1. Создать **бота** и включить у него `inline` режим.
2. Зарегистрировать **игру** в том же *BotFather* и привязываем к боту. Инструкция не нужна. Всё пошагово вам объяснит бот.
3. Пишем игру (`HTML`, `CSS`,`JS`) и заливаем на хостинг. Даже *gitpage* подойдёт.

Остается объединить это всё:

```
// ссылка на игру в сети интернет
let url = 'http://siteWithGame.com'

// название игры (то, что указывали в BotFather)
const gameName = "yourGameName"

// Matches /start
bot.onText(/\/start/, function onPhotoText(msg) {
  bot.sendGame(msg.chat.id, gameName);
});

// Handle callback queries
bot.on('callback_query', function onCallbackQuery(callbackQuery) {
  bot.answerCallbackQuery(callbackQuery.id, { url });
});
```

Т.е. бот может в ответ на какой-то запрос отправить игру `bot.sendGame(...)`.
Грубо говоря, это будет сообщение с картинкой и описанием игры и под этим сообщением `callBack` кнопка, ведущая на сайт с игрой.
При нажатии на кнопку открывается страница с игрой в приложении Telegram.

Вот [здесь](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/tree/master/examples/game) есть реализация и комментарии (*node-telegram-bot-api*).

Comment: Столкнулся с той же проблемой, но не смог воспользоваться ответом. Вот автор ответа приводит код после слов "Остается объединить это всё:" Куда этот код писать? И как донести его до бота, чтобы привязать кнопку "начать игру" к URL? В приведённой ссылке тоже не разобрался. Даётся код. Но я не могу понять, куда его писать ((